# How to populate treenodes from Excel (xls) file using C#

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

I need to update the treenodes from the Excel (xls) files, so name mentioned in specific column of the excel will be added as tree nodes. Ex: B1 is First Element of the node, B2 be 2nd and so on...
If can guide me how to approach or sample project code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to know how to read an excel file, or can you already read the excel file and want to know how to populate a treeview? And if so, which TreeView (WinForms, WPF etc.)?

Comment: I need to read the excel file, and more over i need to understand the approach, if need to update the xls component in list and then populate the treeview. I am using WinForms.

Comment: For reading the Excel file, you could use LinqToExcel (https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel), which also allows you to access the sheets as a simple array of rows. that should make navigation in the excel file easier.